# Number of lines returned by history

Tags: shell, unix, zsh, iterm

On an OSX system, ZSH shell and iterm2 terminal, I am running:

```
$history
```

Results are the 10 last commands.

How do I increase the default number of returned lines?

I can do

```
$history -20
```

And probably also alias this to history, but I do wonder if there is some setup to control this natively.
Also, please do not confuse with HISTSIZE, which is a separated configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be such configuration available.

Option is simply:

```
alias history="history -30"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the history command into a function:

```
h () { history ${1:-\-30} }
```

You get the last 30 history entries by default and still have the option to change the argument to another value.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue in MacOS monterey 12.5.1 - The history command has a number as an input. That number tells the command from which line to start reading the history.

If you want to get ALL your previous commands execute:

`history 0`

This will make sure to show ALL the previous commands